# Adding data to a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

I have a method that reads data from a text file and prints it to the console. I want to use the data that has been read in a `JComboBox`. The combo box will be used for selecting the name in a form.

```
    public class ReadFile {

    private Scanner names;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            names = new Scanner (new File("ChildName.txt"));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not find file");
        }
    }

    public void readFile(){
        while (names.hasNext()){
            String first = names.next();
            String second = names.next();

            System.out.printf("%s %s\n", first,second);
        }
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        names.close();
    }
}
```

Also in my main:

```
    ReadFile file = new ReadFile();
    file.openFile();
    file.readFile();
    file.closeFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for the basics.

In the tutorial they load the data from an array.

In your case you want to load the data one at a time so you would simply use the `addItem(...)` method of the `JComboBox` inside the loop each time you read in a name.

Comment: Using the `addItem` will that automatically add data when more is added to the text file?

Comment: Why would you think that? You have a loop that reads all the data and then closes the file. If the code in the loop is finished executing then how will the addItem() ever be invoked again?

Comment: Ill take out the close file loop then!

Comment: Do you understand how methods and loops work?? Once the loop is finished your code leaves the loop and then leaves the  readFile() method and will never return. When you execute your current code does it keep printing names or does it finish executing. Changing the System.out.println() statement to an addItem(...) statement will not change the behaviour of the reading of the data in the file, only how the data is used.

Comment: @DanTheMan, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

We pass in a string array if we have multiple values we want to display

```
JComboBox b = new JComboBox(new String[]{"String1","String2"})
```

We add one item to combobox.

```
b.addItem("foo");
```