# Display Array contents in a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

I have two classes, one with a class that reads text in a file and puts the data into a array and in the main class I want to add the array contents into a `JComboBox`. But I am getting the error "cannot be resolved to a variable" Any help?

readfiles.java

```
public class readfiles {
String [] names = new String[15];
int i = 0;
public Scanner readNames;

//Opens the file
public void openFile() {
    try {
        readNames = new Scanner(new File("ChildName.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not locate the data file!");
    }
}

//Reads the names in the file
public void readFile() {
    while(readNames.hasNext()) {
        names[i] = readNames.next();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
        System.out.println(names[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

//Closes the file 
public void closeFile() {
    readNames.close();
}
```

}

Main.java

```
   //JComboBox for selecting child
    JLabel selectChildName = new JLabel("Please Select Your Child:");
    sPanel.add(selectChildName);
    JComboBox<String> selectChild = new JComboBox<String>(names); // (names); is the error, cannot be resolved to a variable
                sPanel.add(selectChild);
```

Comment: `names` has content to only the `readFiles` class, you need some way for your `Main` class to reference it, such as a getter maybe. You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: Its frustrating that you ask this question again. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552223/adding-data-to-a-jcombobox. It is not a good solution to use an Array to do this. It is never a good idea to use an Array for something like this because you never know how big to make the Array when reading from a file. Picking a random number is not a flexible design. That is why you were given the solution to add the items to the combo box directly. All you need to do is pass the combo Box to the readFile() method and use the addItem() method. Or you can return the loaded combo box.

Comment: Also, this is a waste of space. When you create the combo box the items in the Array will be copied from the Array to the DefaultComboBoxModel. When you load the items into the combo box directly they are just added to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to access the names vairable in the main because its not in main's scope. To access it create an instance of the readfiles class and then get the names by doing instance.names;

for example,

```
readfiles instance = new readfiles();
instance.openfile();
instance.readfile();
instance.closefile();
JComboBox<String> selectChild = new JComboBox<String>(instance.names);
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `closeFile` ... why that's not all done in `readFile` is beydon me

Comment: Good catch fixed now.

Comment: Okay, I understand now, Thank you.

Comment: @DanTheMan: don't make names public and don't directly access it as Brian is recommending. Again, use a getter method to control access. The whole reason Java is an OOPs language is to reduce complexity (cyclomatic complexity to be exact), and if fields are public, the risk of interactions and the risk of complexity associated bugs increases exponentially. Again, use a getter method as I note in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The names variable is a variable of the readFiles class and thus not visible in your Main class. You need to call a getter method on readFiles to get the array when you need it.